# Create a file under the cursor in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a list of files

```
file1.ext
file2.ext
...
```

How do I create a file with file2.ext name if my cursor is inside file2.ext. Kind of like `gf` only for creating new files (this is a hypothetical situation, just thought might be helpful someday).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to use the `touch` command
with the filename under the cursor as an argument:

```
:map <silent> <leader>cf :!touch <c-r><c-p><cr><cr>
```

But there is a pure Vim solution that is portable across platforms.
The built-in function `writefile` writes the contents of a list to
a file, line by line. Naturally, when the input list is empty, it
creates an empty file. (See `:help writefile()` for details.) We can
take advantage of this side-effect:

```
:map <silent> <leader>cf :call writefile([], expand("<cfile>"), "t")<cr>
```

Note that the filename extraction could be adjusted by using
a different `expand` pattern (see `:help expand()`).

By the way, if one would like not to create a file, but just to open
it for editing, one can define a simpler `gf`-like mapping:

```
:map <leader>gf :e <cfile><cr>
```

where the `:e` command can be replaced with `:tabe` or a similar
command.

Comment: +1 for teaching `<cfile>` instead of `<C-r><C-f>`

Answer (score 2):

I took the excellent answer by ib above and expanded it as follows.  My goal was to use vim to   create new markdown files as needed for a wiki (in this case a Gollum wiki)

I first tried:

```
map <silent> <leader>cf :call writefile([], expand("<cfile>"), "t")<cr>`
```

the above does work as stated in the answer. However, at first I thought it was not working because I did not actually see the file opening in vim.  Using the second bit of code below will open a new file - this is more what I was looking for.  So I combined them and tried:

```
map <leader>cf :e <cfile><cr>
```

but that does not work for a wiki because when you try to create a new file in the wiki using syntax like `[[the-new-file]]` the wiki syntax does not allow for the extension of the file in the brackets.  However, Vim needs to know the extension when creating a new file for this to work.  In this case I used:

```
    map <leader>cf :e <cfile>.md<cr>
```

so I could create new markdown files.  There are ways to further customize this (for example by not hardcoding the extension) but the above works fine for my needs.  If I ever need another extension (for example to save a .wiki file) I will probably just take the simple route and make another map like:

```
    map <leader>cwf :e <cfile>.wiki<cr>
```

As a side benefit you can use the same command to open the already existing markdown file (the standard `gf` command will not work here because the file extension is missing).

Comment: `gf` works if `set suffixesadd=.wiki`.  An improved version of your `cf` would be one that respects `suffixesadd`, at least in the case where it contains only one item.